# Host hacks when no access to hosts file

Tags: windows, security, hosts

I would like to test website where public DNS name is not changed yet. In order to to do that I need to change hosts file on the workstation but the domain security policy prevents me to do so.

Is there any alternative way to do host hack in Windows when user does not have permissions to change hosts file. 
Perhaps a Firefox or Chrome plugin?

Comment: Isn't the point of a policy is that you can't over rule it? If any one could just get round it, then there would be no point in setting it up!

Comment: Maybe you could setup a VM (on which you would then modify your hosts file normally)

Comment: My suggestion is speak to your IT department and say *I would like to test website where public DNS name is not changed yet. In order to to do that I need to change hosts file on the workstation but the domain security policy prevents me to do so.*

Comment: No, I don't have possibility to get exception on the corporate security policy. I have no permission to install anything on the machine I am testing. I can only run applications on my profile, like portableapps.

Comment: @jpkeisala And where is the website you wanted to test? Is it stored locally on your computer? Or is it online with a provider? A provider normally supplies temporary hostnames for testing. If it's local you could just use your own IP (or that of the server, `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://192.168.1.1` or otherwise). Your website should be able to handle a change in hostname/IP.